# Auto generate Unit Tests for windows 8 store apps

Tags: unit-testing, windows-8, windows-runtime

I was able to get "Create Unit Test" option in VS 2012

Ref: http://dl.my/2013/create-unit-tests-function-not-available-or-disabled/#comment-63

But the problem is, in the Create Unit Test window, I am not able to expand the project.
It gives me error saying something like:
Assembly reference cannot be resolved

With little more investigation, I found that the target framework should be same for all the project in order to avoid this error.
But for store apps, I cannot set target framework (This field is grayed out)

If I try "Create Unite Test" option in some other project which uses same target framework as that of Unit Test Project, the option works fine and code is generated.

is there a way to make it work for windows 8 store apps?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Unit Test Code Generator plug-in?